# Wireshark sms Plugin Install

Tags: wireshark, gsm, packets, wireshark-dissector

How do I add isi-wireshark-plugin [Link Here](https://github.com/shr-project/isi-wireshark-plugin/) to the wireshark software. I'm quite new to wireshark and its interface. Also i would like to know on how can i analyse GSM packets which show as SLL in wireshark is there a separate tool to analyse GSM packets. I'm unable to find proper documents maybe i'm using a wrong keyword to search, looking for guidance help much appreciated

Also wireshark platform I have is in windows and Kali Linux

Comment: Have a look here [GSM Protocol Family](http://wiki.wireshark.org/GsmProtocolFamily?action=show&redirect=GSM) and [Capture SS7](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/SS7?highlight=%28SS7%29). Also (since I like P1labs) see [SS7 in Wireshark](http://labs.p1sec.com/2013/04/04/ss7-traffic-analysis-with-wireshark/)

Comment: My protocol in wireshark says SLL which when i researched said its nokia Phonet packets ( 0x00f5 unknown protocol )

Comment: Do not worry about SLL. See this Wireshark page: [SLL](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SLL). You will always see SLL when you "capture any device" (e.g. tcpdump -i any)